# Python - Modules not working

Tags: python, module, path

So i downloaded the "kivy" module (using the 'command prompt') as shown during this video "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B79miUFD_ss&list=PLGLfVvz_LVvTAZ-OcNIXe05srJRXaJRd9"

But whenever i try to run this code:

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.9.0')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Label

# Inherit Kivy's App class which represents the window
# for our widgets
# HelloKivy inherits all the fields and methods
# from Kivy
class HelloKivy(App):

    # This returns the content we want in the window
    def build(self):

        # Return a label widget with Hello Kivy
        return Label(text="Hello Kivy")

helloKivy = HelloKivy()
helloKivy.run()
```

It says the module doesn't exist?
How do i find the path of this module (and other modules)?

Comment: Are you using correct version of Python? Did you install it into same path you are using? Hard to say without more information.

Comment: `kivy.require('1.9.0')`.. you do have kivy version 1.9.0 installed?